# Apple Mach-O-Linker Error CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, mach-o

I've been trying to get my app up and running. From what I could tell the app was missing Cocoapods as a dependency. So. I installed and added Cocoapods. But I'm still getting the same error for whatever reason. I'm an inexperienced developer trying to teach himself I must add.

> Ld
>   /Users/bfarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Umbrella-cspuzusfqmqgnwdqfhtiyivaqwke/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Umbrella.app/Umbrella
>   normal i386
>       cd "/Users/bfarag/Desktop/The Nerdery/BRAVO.iOS.CodeChallenge"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/bfarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Umbrella-cspuzusfqmqgnwdqfhtiyivaqwke/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/bfarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Umbrella-cspuzusfqmqgnwdqfhtiyivaqwke/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/bfarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Umbrella-cspuzusfqmqgnwdqfhtiyivaqwke/Build/Intermediates/Umbrella.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Umbrella.build/Objects-normal/i386/Umbrella.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lPods-Umbrella-AFNetworking -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration
>   -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework Accelerate -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lPods -lPods-Umbrella -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/bfarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Umbrella-cspuzusfqmqgnwdqfhtiyivaqwke/Build/Intermediates/Umbrella.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Umbrella.build/Objects-normal/i386/Umbrella_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/bfarag/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Umbrella-cspuzusfqmqgnwdqfhtiyivaqwke/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Umbrella.app/Umbrella

```
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: Linker Flags]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This error usually occurs either when you don't have the correct frameworks (might be missing one) or when you don't have the right thing in linker flags.

Go to the main page for the app (on the navigation thing on the left click on your apps name or the top section) -> Build Settings and under Linker Flags, make sure there is nothing in your Other Linker Flags. I had this same error when I had -ObjC in my other Linker Flags.

You might also want to try adding -lPods to your Other Linker Flags or adding the CoreGraphics framework if you don't already have it.

Good luck

Comment: Same! Thank you! So many unsolved tickets with this problem; glad I finally found this one.

Comment: I believe that @dadalar answer is more correct than this one, it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted $(inherited) from my Other Linker Flags and it worked. Wish I had found this while I still had my hair.

Answer (score 17):

Open workspace file, not project file. Cocoapods automatically creates a xcworkspace file on the same directory as xcproject file.

Comment: Yeah that's how I open it.

Comment: Maybe project file is manually edited and broken. Can you try using pod update command again, so it can fix this kind of reference problems?

Comment: Are my linker flags okay (check the new image at the top of my post)

Answer (score 5):

Xcode started displaying this message and I tried pretty much everything to solve it. What finally did the trick for me was deleting all content from `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: Classic iOS dev.