# GCM Library errors: Integration GCM in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

What I have done after 2 days of reading stack overflow:

Keywords to problem: "***Apple-Mach-O Linker Error***", "***libGcmLib.a(GCMRmqManager.o)***", ***sqlite3***", "***GCMRmq2PersistentStore***"

- Installed latest pod.
- Tested 'Other Linker Flags' -ObJC and empty as well.
- Cleaned the project and rebuilt. Deleted project and recreated, no help. Header is in the right path and properly configured.
- Manually copied dependencies but it didn't help.
- Manually copied new source code from Google's Github as well as their recently updated 'GCM Playground', nothing worked.
- Integrated CoreData.framework to no avail.
- Tried these solutions: 
  [Apple Mach-O Linker Error when compiling for device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device), 
  [CocoaPods adds incorrect Other Linker Flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953498/cocoapods-adds-incorrect-other-linker-flags), [Google Cloud Messaging Bridging Header import fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219849/google-cloud-messaging-bridging-header-import-fails), [Xcode - symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 (iOS Lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346637/xcode-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-ios-lib), [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64), [Apple Mach-O-Linker Error CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263637/apple-mach-o-linker-error-cocoapods), [Swift iOS don't recognize GCM library imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629768/swift-ios-dont-recognize-gcm-library-imports)

So I am stuck. How do I solve the problem(s) displayed in the image below: "*sqlite3*.... ", referenced from: "GCMRmq2PersistentStore in libGcmLib.a(GCMRmqManager.o)?

IMAGE
[image]

Comment: Did you add the GCM via Cocoapods? If not, you can do `pod 'GoogleCloudMessaging'` in your podfile

Comment: Yes I did. It is mentioned in the links I provided. Didn't help either.

Comment: Were you able to get the GCM iOS quickstart work on its own? https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm

Comment: is cocoapods mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

GCM seems to be using `sqlite3` in the library. You should link your app against it to build it. You tried integrating `CoreData` but it should rather have been sqlite3.

You should also check CocoaPod's generated `xcconfig` file i.e. `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig` file and the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` option should have -l"sqlite3" in it. That should have linked it for you.