# FirebaseAnalytics framework not found

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm having a problem with FirebaseAnalytics since running a pod update.  I get the error

```
ld: framework not found FirebaseAnalytics
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and reviewed the answers to this error from other people.
In the case of my app, 'FrameworkSearchPaths' (default and release) looks like this:

```
$(inherited) 
"$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/GTMSessionFetcher" 
"$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/GoogleToolboxForMac" 
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks" 
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/frameworks" 
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/frameworks" 
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks" 
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks" 
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseStorage/Frameworks/frameworks" 
"${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks" 
"${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks"
```

The pod folder looks like this...

[image]

My podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'

target 'MyApp' do
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
end

target 'MyAppUITests' do
end
```

Does anyone have a sequential approach to debugging this error?  I didn't have the problem before the `pod update`.
I've tried a mac restart, reinstalling cocoapods, and re-running both `pod update` and `pod install`.  I'm working with the latest xCode version.

*********** Update ***************

I've tried some more things:

- changing the order of Framework Search Paths, putting the call to FirebaseAnalytics at the end
- running shift-command-F to find references to 'FirebaseAnalytics' to see if there are any duplicates or patterns of references that look wrong (didn't see anything)
- deleting FirebaseAnalytics and running re-install
- the solution proposed in this answer [Apple Mach-O-Linker Error CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263637/apple-mach-o-linker-error-cocoapods?rq=1) by deleting the contents of Other Linker Flags

None of these fix the issue I'm having

More ideas on how to debug the problem are welcome

Comment: Did you reinstall the right version of cocoapods? Could be part of the problem.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue since I had it working with the same version of cocoapods before the pod update.  The version I'm using is cocoapods-1.1.1

Comment: Did you try adding "${PODS_ROOT}/Frameworks" to the list of Framework Search Paths?

Comment: I just tried it but it throws a warning: {ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/shaneoseasnain/Desktop/AppsDev/MyApp/Pods/Frameworks'}

Comment: After the other things I mention above in the update, I tried adding  "${PODS_ROOT}/Frameworks" to the list of Framework Search Paths again.  This time, there no warning showing with the error though.

Comment: One more delete and reinstall of frameworks solved it

Answer (score 2):

Go to OtherLinkerFlags in build settings of target & remove 'FirebaseAnalytics" & '-framework' from there.
This works for me.